# Why does my tower of hanoi algorithm not work?

Tags: c, towers-of-hanoi

I need to write a hanoi recursion algorithm with 3 parameters. This is what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h> #include <stdio.h>

void hanoi(int m, int i, int j);
void move(int start, int end);

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 3;
    printf("Enter how many disks you want to move: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int m = n;
    hanoi(m,i,j);

}

void hanoi(int m, int i, int j){    
    if (m==1)
    {
        move(i,j);
        return;
    }
    hanoi(m-1,i,2);
    move(i,j);
    hanoi(m-1,2,j);

}

void move(int start, int end){
    printf("A disk moves from position %d. to %d.\n", start,end);
}
```

The output for n=3 is the following:

```
Enter how many disks you want to move: 3
A disk moves from position 1. to 2.
A disk moves from position 1. to 2.
A disk moves from position 2. to 2.
A disk moves from position 1. to 3.
A disk moves from position 2. to 2.
A disk moves from position 2. to 3.
A disk moves from position 2. to 3.
```

I looked at other algorithms, I know there is tons of those for solving the goold old hanoi problem. However, they all have 4 parameters and use characters, whereas I would like to only use numbers and leave out the auxiliary tower parameter in my function. How can I fix it? For n=1 and n=2 the algorithm works fine.

Comment: please use descriptive variable names.

Comment: the problem is that `2` is hardcoded.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I see... How can I bypass that? Plugging in a variable with the value 2 at the beginning of the function wouldnt solve it.. :/

Comment: you need the number of the 3rd peg. you already know the other two. it's not that difficult ;)

Comment: `Other_peg = (1+2+3) - i - j`.

Comment: @chux I see. Just realised as well that putting in a constant number into the third peg wont solve it with this approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code needs to use the *other* peg, rather than `2` as commented by [@Karoly Horvath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266927/why-does-my-tower-of-hanoi-algorithm-not-work?noredirect=1#comment67795113_40266927)

```
void hanoi(int m, int i, int j){    
    if (m==1) {
        move(i,j);
        return;
    }
    int Other_peg = (1+2+3) - i - j;
    hanoi(m-1,i,Other_peg);
    move(i,j);
    hanoi(m-1,Other_peg,j);
}
```